# Additional condition withing partition over

Tags: sql, select

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rgLXTu3VysD3kRwBAQK3a4/3

My problem here is that I want function partition over to start counting the rows only from certain time range.

In this example, if I would add `rn = 1` at the end, order_id = 5 would be excluded from the results (because partition is ordering by `paid_date` and there's `order_id = 6` with earlier date) but it shouldn't be as I want that time range for partition starts from `'2019-01-10'`.

Adding condition `rn = 1`expected output should be `order_id 3,5,11,15`, now its only `3,11,15`

- it should include only orders with `is_paid = 0` that are the first one within given time range (if there's preceeding order with `is_paid = 1` it shouldn't be counted)

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: adding condition `rn = 1`, it should be ``order_id 3,5,11,15``, now its only `3,11,15`

- it should include only orders with paid_status = 0 that are the first one within given time range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correlated subquery with `not exists`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c7aaf83f2291e1ddde76cd03986a21bc)**

```
 SELECT order_id, customer_id, amount, is_paid, paid_date,  rn FROM (
        SELECT o.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY paid_date,order_id) rn
        FROM orders o
         WHERE paid_date between '2019-01-10' 
    and '2019-01-15'
    ) x  where rn=1 and not exists (select 1 from orders o1 where x.order_id=o1.order_id
    and is_paid=1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
order_id    customer_id amount  is_paid paid_date      rn
3           101          30      0  10/01/2019 00:00:00 1
5           102          15      0  10/01/2019 00:00:00 1
11          104          31      0  10/01/2019 00:00:00 1
15          105          11      0  10/01/2019 00:00:00 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, anyway, am I missing something or it can be simplified into:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=47ce7bcbd5a1d02bd0a2c4758f0d432f

(remove `not exists` subquery and just add `is_paid = 0` clause?)

Answer (score 0):

If priority should be given to order_id then put that before paid date in the partition function order by clause, this will solve your issue.

```
SELECT order_id, customer_id, amount, is_paid, paid_date,  rn FROM (
            SELECT o.*, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY  order_id,paid_date) rn
            FROM orders o
        ) x WHERE is_paid = 0 and paid_date between 
        '2019-01-10' and '2019-01-15' and rn=1
```

Since you need the paid date to be ordered first you need to imply a where condition in the partitioning table in order to avoid unnecessary dates interrupting the partition function.

```
SELECT order_id, customer_id, amount, is_paid, paid_date,  rn FROM (
        SELECT o.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY paid_date, order_id) rn
        FROM orders o
  where paid_date between '2019-01-10' and '2019-01-15'
    ) x WHERE is_paid = 0 and rn=1
```

Comment: I used paid_date in the order by on purpose, it should be ordered first on date, then if it's the same on order_id, not otherwise